# Debug a C++ dynamic library loaded by a script with netbeans

Tags: c++, netbeans, gdb

I want to debug a dynamic library with gdb in netbeans. This library is loaded by a program which is executed by a script. I can debug with the attach function in netbeans. But i can not stop the program at the beginning. Is the a way to start the script directly with gdb?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Install gdbserver on your computer.
2. Edit your script so instead of starting your program it runs gdbserver localhost:port yourprogram
   (eg. gdbserver localhost:2000 dist/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/cppapplication_2 )
3. Install gdbserver Netbeans plugin.
        - Menu Tools -> Plugins
        - Select Available Plugins Tab
        - Search for gdbserver
4. Run your script to start your application in gdb server.
5. Set a breakpoint line at a convenient starting location.
6. Menu Debug -> Attach Debugger
7. Select gdbserver in drop down.
8. Set target to "remote localhost:2000"
9. Set Project to correct project.
10. Click Ok. It should connect and end up on the breakpoint you set.